# Concrete5 add sub page (page not found)

Tags: concrete5

I try to add sub page of home page. After i clicked add page button, it redirects to page not found. This happened also when I tried to log in via custom login page, but then I created new controller, and it works. I guess they are a similar problem.

This is the form to add page. The action value is `http://rc.bappenas.go.id/index.php?cID=5023&ccm_token=1441182812:061784e9bfe5b07adb7e5c876e010d09`

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $c->getCollectionAction()?>" id="ccmAddPage" onsubmit="jQuery.fn.dialog.showLoader()" class="dialog-form">       
<input type="hidden" name="rel" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['rel']?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctID" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['ctID']?>" />

<div id="ccm-add-page-information">

    <h4><?php echo t('Standard Properties')?></h4>
    <?php  $form = Loader::helper('form'); ?>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <?php echo $form->label('cName', t('Name'))?>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="cName" value="" class="text span6" onKeyUp="ccm_updateAddPageHandle()" ></div>
    </div>


    <div class="clearfix">
        <?php echo $form->label('cHandle', t('URL Slug'))?>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="cHandle" class="span3" value="" id="cHandle">
        <img src="<?php echo ASSETS_URL_IMAGES?>/loader_intelligent_search.gif" width="43" height="11" id="ccm-url-slug-loader" style="display: none" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">      
        <?php echo $form->label('cDatePublic', t('Public Date/Time'))?>
        <div class="input">
        <?php 
        $dt = Loader::helper('form/date_time');
        echo $dt->datetime('cDatePublic' );
        ?> 
        </div>
    </div>      

    <div class="clearfix">
        <?php echo $form->label('cDescription', t('Description'))?>
        <div class="input">
        <textarea name="cDescription" rows="4" class="span6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <?php 
    $attribs = $ct->getAvailableAttributeKeys();
    $mc = $ct->getMasterTemplate();
    ?>

<?php  if (count($attribs) > 0) { ?>
    <h4><?php echo t('Custom Attributes')?></h4>


<?php   
ob_start();

foreach($attribs as $ak) { 

    if (is_object($mc)) { 
        $caValue = $mc->getAttributeValueObject($ak);
    }       
    ?>


    <div class="clearfix">
        <label><?php echo $ak->getAttributeKeyName()?></label>
        <div class="input">
        <?php echo $ak->render('composer', $caValue); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php  } 
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); ?>  

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php  
$v = View::getInstance();
$headerItems = $v->getHeaderItems();
foreach($headerItems as $item) {
    if ($item instanceof CSSOutputObject) {
        $type = 'CSS';
    } else {
        $type = 'JAVASCRIPT';
    } ?>
     ccm_addHeaderItem("<?php echo $item->file?>", '<?php echo $type?>');
    <?php  
} 
?>
</script>

<?php  print $contents; ?>

    <?php  } ?>

</div>



<div class="dialog-buttons">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jQuery.fn.dialog.closeTop();" class="ccm-button-left btn"><?php echo t('Cancel')?></a>
    <input type="submit" onclick="$('#ccmAddPage').submit()" class="btn primary ccm-button-right" value="<?php echo t('Add Page')?>" />
</div>  

<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="processCollection" value="1">

</form>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some source code.

Comment: @Kiki I added some code

Comment: Just to be sure, you're logging in as admin when you are trying these, right?  I had a similar issue when testing user permissions, my user didn't have read/write access to the Drafts page.

Comment: @BoydDensmore thanks for your response. anw I already solved this. I messed with some session cookie stuff.